# Bluetooth HDP implementation on android does not work

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I want to get some data to android (Jelly Bean) from Personal Health Devices using Bluetooth HDP. I tried to use the official sample app provided by android developers, and then I tried this demo app ( [A-D-HDP-Android-Demo](https://github.com/andengineering/A-D-HDP-Android-Demo)) from A&D too. However, channel connection state changes from CONNECTING to DISCONNECTED almost all the time. I could get to CONNECTED state only twice out of hundreds of trials :-/

I am using weighing scale (from A&D Medical, UC-321PBT-C), and blood pressure monitor (from A&D Medical,  UA-767PBT-C). Android device that I am using: Sony Xperia S, API level 16.

Would be great if anyone could provide me some short guide on how to get it work.

Comment: Hi there, did you ever solved the problem?

Comment: Not really :( Why did you ask? Can you provide me with some useful tutorial?

Comment: Hi @longwalker we ran into the same problem but it's random and doesn't always occur. Was just wondering if you ever solved it.

Comment: Hey @JamesWong, I am glad it worked for you. Could you maybe share your code for service (managing the bluetooth connection)? My skype username: samatkg1. I could not write to you a private message, and I don't wanna write my email here.  Thanks!